# Telugu and Kanada language pdf generation using fpdf

Tags: php, itext, fpdf

I want to generate report in multiple languages. However, I derive the words to be displayed in the report from mySQL on fpdf. For other regional languages tamil, hindi, and malayalam i convert the words to unicode and print on my pdf using fpdf. Similarly I want for Telugu and Kannada. Also I tried using tpdf with the below code

```
require('tfpdf.php');
$pdf = new tFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
// Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
$pdf->AddFont('Mandali','','Mandali.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('Mandali','',14);
$telugu2="నమూనా సంఖ్య";
$pdf->Write(25,$telugu2);
```

But the result is coming like the below one

నమూనా
సంఖ
్
య

I want the output to be నమూనా సంఖ్య

Comment: Complex scripts are not supported.